# VBA Excel - Using the xlFilterAllDatesInPeriod"Month" based on user input

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple userform that lists all the months in a year using a ComboBox. There is a "Close" button and a "Run" button. When the "Run" button is clicked, I want the column in the active sheet to be filtered using the "xlFilterAllDatesInPeriod-month" criteria and the month should be chosen by the user from the ComboBox.

```
'List of months
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
     With ComboBox1
       .AddItem "January"
       .AddItem "February"
       .AddItem "March"
       .AddItem "April"
       .AddItem "May"
       .AddItem "June"
       .AddItem "July"
       .AddItem "August"
       .AddItem "September"
       .AddItem "October"
       .AddItem "November"
       .AddItem "December"
    End With
End Sub

'Close button
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() 
   Unload Me
End Sub

'Run the code button
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   If ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
       MsgBox "Please choose a month"
   Else
       Sheets("MASTER LIST").Select
       ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$T$289").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:= _
           xlFilterAllDatesInPeriod"Month", Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
       Unload Me
   End If
End Sub
```

These are codes that I have now. The "Month" part on the Criteria1 should be based on user input. Please advice on how I can make it work.

Appreciate the help and thanks in advance!

Comment: If items in the combobox  are correctly ordered, you should be able to use `xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodJanuary + ComboBox1.ListIndex` since ListIndex is 0-based and xlFilterAllDatesInPeriod... are continuous values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Select Case to convert your combobox selection to the relevant enum constant.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   dim xlMonth as long

   xlMonth = 0
   select case ComboBox1.value
       case "January"
           xlmonth = xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodJanuary
       case "February"
           xlmonth = xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodFebruary
       case "March"
           xlmonth = xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodMarch
       case "April"
           xlmonth = xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodApril
       case "May"
           xlmonth = xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodMay
       case "June"
           xlmonth = xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodJune
       case "July"
           xlmonth = xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodJuly
       case "August"
           xlmonth = xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodAugust
       case "September"
           xlmonth = xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodSeptember
       case "October"
           xlmonth = xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodOctober
       case "November"
           xlmonth = xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodNovember
       case "December"
           xlmonth = xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodDecember
       case else
           MsgBox "Please choose a month"
    end select

    if cbool(xlmonth) then
       with workSheets("MASTER LIST")
           .Select
           .Range("$A$2:$T$289").AutoFilter Field:=15, _
               Criteria1:=xlmonth , Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
       end with
       Unload Me
    End If

End Sub
```